# how to assign a value to a variable based on its relationship with another data frame in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

My question is I have a data frame contains all the start and end date and corresponding ids for each type. I want to use this data frame to assign the id to another data frame based on the date. Specifically, if the date in the second data frame between the first one's start and end date, it will be signed the same ID as the first one.

```
#Here are two data frames
m1=pd.DataFrame({'type':['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                 'id':[1,2,3,1,2,3],
                 'startdate':[20120201,20120301,20130401,20130301,20130501,20140601],
                 'enddate':[20120218,20120324,20130425,20130312,20130521,20140706]})

m2=pd.DataFrame({'type':['A','A','B','B'],
                 'pin':[12,33,25,47],
                 'date':[20120213,20130411,20130504,20140704]})

#ideally the result should be 

m3=pd.DataFrame({'type':['A','A','B','B'],
                 'pin':[12,33,25,47],
                 'date':[20120213,20130411,20130504,20140704],
                 'id':[1,3,2,3]})
```

I can't figure out a better way to do that. Because there are millions of records I need a more efficient way to run the codes. Any ideas? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to your problem.

Effectively, I will try to join m1 and m2 together into a single dataframe using merged/join.

After getting the merged dataframe, i will then do the test to ensure that the 'date' column fails within the 'startdate' and the 'enddate'

Therefore your code will look like this

```
## merged dataframe
df_merged = pd.merge(m2, m1, how='inner', left_on='type', right_on='type')

## create function to check that date fails between start and end date
f = lambda x : x if x['date'] >  x['startdate'] and x['date'] < x['enddate'] else     None

## apply function to dataframe
df_merged=df_merged.apply(f, axis=1)

## drop na values
df_merged.dropna()
```

Comment: +1, and you should probably convert `date` `startdate` etc into `datetime` `dtype`, in case there are values such as `991001` instead of `19991001`.

Comment: Yes. That will optimal.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply! I thought about this but actually my m1 has 70,000+ records and my m2 has 4000+ records I am just afraid that if I merge them together the computer will run out of memory. I will try your codes later on when I finish something in my python in case it will crash.

Comment: I did try that on my real data but somehow I don't know why after the function was applied, the result became two columns; one column contained the contacted string of each row and the other is the index. something like `type A startdate 201302003 enddate 20130207 id 2 date 20130205` as the whole in one cell I don't know what might go wrong here..

Answer (score 0):

Actually the accepted answer does not work for me because of the weirdness of my data I mentioned in the comments, so I get the result from another way:

```
 ## merged dataframe
df_merged = pd.merge(m2, m1, how='inner', left_on='type', right_on='type')

## create the index(True and False) of the rows you want to keep
keepindex =(df_merged['date'] >  df_merged['startdate']) & (df_merged['date'] < df_merged['enddate'])

## subset the data frame by the index
df_merged=df_merged[keepindex]
```